# Strip html from string Ruby on Rails

Tags: html, ruby, string, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm working with Ruby on Rails, Is there a way to strip `html` from a string using sanitize or equal method and keep only text inside value attribute on input tag?

Answer (score 151, accepted):

There's a `strip_tags` method in `ActionView::Helpers::SanitizeHelper`:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html#method-i-strip_tags

Edit: for getting the text inside the value attribute, you could use something like Nokogiri with an Xpath expression to get that out of the string.

Answer (score 208):

If we want to use this in model

```
ActionView::Base.full_sanitizer.sanitize(html_string)
```

which is the code in "strip_tags" method

Comment: This works but referring to ActionView from the mdoel is awkward. More cleanly you can `require 'html/sanitizer'` and instantiate your own sanitizer with `HTML::FullSanitizer.new`.

Comment: @nhaldimann, `require 'html/sanitizer'` raises error so I have to use: `Rails::Html::FullSanitizer.new` (http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/HTML/FullSanitizer.html#method-i-sanitize)

Comment: I'm using `Rails::Html::FullSanitizer.new.sanitize(string)` with Rails 7

Answer (score 36):

```
ActionView::Base.full_sanitizer.sanitize(html_string)
```

White list of tags and attributes can be specified as bellow

```
ActionView::Base.full_sanitizer.sanitize(html_string, :tags => %w(img br p), :attributes => %w(src style))
```

Above statement allows tags **img**, **br** and **p** and attributes **src** and **style**.

Answer (score 35):

Yes, call this: `sanitize(html_string, tags:[])`

Answer (score 10):

I've used the Loofah library, as it is suitable for both HTML and XML (both documents and string fragments). It is the engine behind the html sanitizer gem. I'm simply pasting the code example to show how simple it is to use.

[Loofah Gem](https://github.com/flavorjones/loofah)

```
unsafe_html = "ohai! <div>div is safe</div> <script>but script is not</script>"

doc = Loofah.fragment(unsafe_html).scrub!(:strip)
doc.to_s    # => "ohai! <div>div is safe</div> "
doc.text    # => "ohai! div is safe "
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
white_list_sanitizer = Rails::Html::WhiteListSanitizer.new
WHITELIST = ['p','b','h1','h2','h3','h4','h5','h6','li','ul','ol','small','i','u']


[Your, Models, Here].each do |klass| 
  klass.all.each do |ob| 
    klass.attribute_names.each do |attrs|
      if ob.send(attrs).is_a? String
        ob.send("#{attrs}=", white_list_sanitizer.sanitize(ob.send(attrs), tags: WHITELIST, attributes: %w(id style)).gsub(/<p>\s*<\/p>\r\n/im, ''))
        ob.save
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: There is also `Rails::Html::FullSanitizer.new` if you don't want to specify a whitelist.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove all html tags you can use

```
   htm.gsub(/<[^>]*>/,'')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me in rails 6.1.3:

```
.errors-description
  = sanitize(message, tags: %w[div span strong], attributes: %w[class])
```

Answer (score 0):

If your HTML is coming from `ActionText`, you can do `.to_plain_text`:

```
@my_string = <p>My HTML String</p>
@my_string.to_plain_text
=> My HTML String
```

https://www.rubydoc.info/github/rails/rails/ActionText%2FContent:to_plain_text

Comment: What is this? `.to_plain_text` isn't a thing in the core.

Comment: @JoshuaPinter You are correct. Just updated my answer. Thanks!