# Detecting string that will render as nothing in Ruby on Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a rich text field that is sending data in an HTML format. I want to store it in a database, but only if it will actually render as something.

Example:

```
"hello world" => true
"<br><b></b>" => false
"<br><b>How are you today?</b>" => true
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check if output of `ActionView::Base.full_sanitizer.sanitize` is blank:

```
ActionView::Base.full_sanitizer.sanitize("<b>").blank?
# => true
ActionView::Base.full_sanitizer.sanitize("<b> </b>").blank?
#=> true
ActionView::Base.full_sanitizer.sanitize("<b>a</b>").blank?
#=> false
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31180237/580346

Comment: No idea why I didn't think of this. Works great, thanks!